# Showing pop-up using using bootstrap in angular 4

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Hi I have created a pop up on a button click on html , it's working fine .
 Below is my HTML code :
    
    {{title}}
    {{signUp}}

```
<div #myModal class="modal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="modal-title">
                {{modalTitle}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Username : <input type="text" placeholder="username">
          <br>
          <br>
          Password : <input type="password" placeholder="*****">         
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="btn1"type = "button" class="btn btn-primary">click me</button>
                <button type = "button" class="btn btn-secondary" class="data-dismiss">close</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Below is my angular code :

```
import { Component, Input ,ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core'
declare var jQuery:any;

@Component({
selector: 'header-comp',
templateUrl: `../html/header.component.html`,
styleUrls: [`../css/header.component.css`]
})
export class HeaderComponent
{
constructor(private el : ElementRef){}
title ="Welcome !!";
signUp ="signUp";
modalTitle ="Please enter your details!!!";
//@ViewChild('myModal')  displayModal:ElementRef ;
@ViewChild('myModal')  displayModal;

showSignUpModal()
{
    //let displayModalElem = this.displayModal.nativeElement;
    jQuery(this.displayModal.nativeElement).modal('show');
   // jQuery(displayModalElem).modal('show');
}
}
```

It is working fine , but my problem is I am new to angular and I do not understand what is happening actually I went through many stackoverflow questions youtube tutorials, people have answered how to achieve this but I couldn't get proper explanation why is this happening , SO I have few queries regarding the code that it would be helpful if some one explains.

1) `<div #myModal class="modal" role="dialog">`

Why are we using "#myModal" instead of id="myModal"?

2)`   //@ViewChild('myModal')  displayModal:ElementRef ;
       @ViewChild('myModal')  displayModal;
       jQuery(this.displayModal.nativeElement).modal('show');

I have tried with both above code that is taking an ElementRef in @ViewChild as in the first line and without taking it as in the second line , and both of them work?? How is it possible ? Is ElemntRef optional ?? Angular official documnet doesn't explain it .

3) Why are we using jquery to show modal, is there no way to call it using only Angular ??

Answer (score 0):

Hey so here are the answers for your qeustion..

1) `<div #myModal class="modal" role="dialog">`

and : so #myModal here is your Template reference variable, using which we can access DOM properties, for example, To fetch DOM properties like you want the role of your dialog you can access it like myModal.role . similar you can use to get its id or anything that you want.

for more you can visit [here](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-template-reference-variable-example) :

2) 2)` //@ViewChild('myModal') displayModal:ElementRef ; @ViewChild('myModal') displayModal; jQuery(this.displayModal.nativeElement).modal('show');

I have tried with both above code that is taking an ElementRef in @ViewChild as in the first line and without taking it as in the second line, and both of them work?? How is it possible? Is ElemntRef optional ?? Angular official document doesn't explain it.

ans :  If you need the ElementRef of a component, you can't use a template variable. If the element is a component, you'll get the component instance instead. A template variable only returns ElementRef for plain HTML elements.

To get ElementRef of a component, you need to use @ViewChild()
`@ViewChild('myModal') displayModal:ElementRef ;` @ViewChild('myModal') displayModal; 
the way you used.

3) Why are we using jquery to show modal, is there no way to call it using only Angular ??

ans : No there is simpler way too. making boolean value true and false using ngshow . so when you want to display model make its value to true and to hide false. basically to show and hide div example

Hope this helps you to understand.